# перезагрузка страницы при свайпе вниз в мобильных браузерах

Tags: javascript, css

В мобильных браузерах реализована такая фича, что если свайпить сверху вниз и при этом скрол находится в вернем положении, то запуститься перезагрузка страницы.
Видел подобный вопрос, но там автор использовал костыль `overflow: hidden` на тег `body`.
Меня же интересуют более правильные решения отмены этого действия.

Comment: Повесьте на боди магическое свойство overscroll-behavior: none;

Comment: @GGO к сожалению оно не работает в некоторых браузерах, например safari

Comment: я понимаю, но это не так просто отключить) это уже интерфейс самого браузера, а не странички(

Comment: @GGO не просто, значит возможно?

Comment: А если отслеживать движение пальца вниз через тач-события и возвращать false.  https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Touch_events

Comment: гляньте сюда, может подойдёт https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/11/overscroll-behavior

Comment: @Bear Vorkuta это первое что приходит в голову, помниться пробовал, но результата не дало, там насколько помню с пассивностью события заморочка. Надо будет поэкспериментировать еще.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня получилось такое решение:

```
var lastY = 1;
document.addEventListener("touchmove", function (event) {
    var lastS = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    if(lastS == 0 && (lastY-event.touches[0].clientY)<0 && event.cancelable){
        event.preventDefault(); 
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
    lastY = event.touches[0].clientY;
},{passive: false});
```

Comment: Прикольно, спасибо.

Comment: Но есть одна проблемка. Допустим есть диалог, в нем скролящийся контент. Так вот если проскролить немного вниз, отпустить палец и поскролить вверх - скрол не работает. Если не отпуская пальца елозить вверх вниз, все работает)))

Comment: @pepel_xD Да, тоже заметил такое поведение, необходимо проверять на какой элемент мы нажимаем через event.target, и если его scrollTop не равен 0, то не отменять событие, но при этом мы будем попадать нажатием на элементы в скролящемся окне и нам нужно будет через parentNode определять не находится ли случайно наша цель в скролящемся контенте, а если скролящийся контент в скролящимся контенте? задача усложнится, поэтому проще будет сделать адаптацию к определенному примеру

Comment: Да, так и сделал, правда добавил цикл по parent на предмет наличия скрола в нем, ведь скрол может находиться в "дедушке" или "прадедушке", ну а корневой элемент диалога известен.